# Client JAX-WS RI duplicating requests

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

We have a JAX-WS RI client -it's initialised in a stateless bean and reused-, sometimes when we invoke it, it make many duplicate http requests to the service internally.

This is a glance to the relevant sections of the log:

```
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:15.030-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Request message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube ] Instance [ 386 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:15.031-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Request message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube ] Instance [ 385 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:15.032-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Request message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube ] Instance [ 383 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:15.032-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Request message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube ] Instance [ 384 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:15.033-0400||com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Request message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientTube ] Instance [ 382 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:15.034-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Request message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe ] Instance [ 380 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:15.034-0400||com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Request message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientTube ] Instance [ 381 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.314-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Response message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe ] Instance [ 380 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.315-0400||com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Response message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientTube ] Instance [ 381 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.316-0400||com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Response message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientTube ] Instance [ 382 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.317-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Response message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube ] Instance [ 383 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.318-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Response message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube ] Instance [ 384 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.319-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Response message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube ] Instance [ 385 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.320-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Response message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube ] Instance [ 386 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.323-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Request message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube ] Instance [ 385 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.323-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Request message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube ] Instance [ 386 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.324-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Request message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube ] Instance [ 384 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.325-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Request message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube ] Instance [ 383 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.326-0400||com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Request message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientTube ] Instance [ 382 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.327-0400||com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Request message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientTube ] Instance [ 381 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.328-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Request message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe ] Instance [ 380 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.412-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Response message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe ] Instance [ 380 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.413-0400||com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Response message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientTube ] Instance [ 381 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.414-0400||com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Response message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientTube ] Instance [ 382 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.415-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Response message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube ] Instance [ 383 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.416-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Response message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube ] Instance [ 384 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.417-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Response message received in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube ] Instance [ 385 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
[#|2013-07-29T16:50:22.418-0400||com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Response message processed in Tube [ com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube ] Instance [ 386 ] Engine [ Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2: Stub for https://www.mywebservice.com/blahblah ] Thread [ http-thread-pool-9680(4) ]:
```

#### What is the cause of this?

#### May reusing the SOAP client be the cause of this effect?

#### Is there a way to configure this library to not do this (supposing it is an expected behaviour)?

Comment: After studying your logs, request received twice but processed once,Guess might be an issue with the log configuration for class level com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube

Comment: Sounds reasonable, Kiran. nonetheless, I'm seeing in the logs how a http request is repeated at least twice receiving two different responses. :(

Also, do you know what the instance number stands for? I think it may be related...